# Is it possible to toggle the icon of this right-click context menu toggle switch?

Tags: icons, context-menu

I have this toggle switch that starts and/or stops the WinDefend service from  Windows 10 right-click Context menu. At present it only has one icon but I want it to be able to change icons too whenever it toggles the service. So that when it starts the Windefend service, it shows the EppManifest.dll,7 icon and when it stops the WinDefend service, it shows the EppManifest.dll,8 icon.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\Toggle Windows Defender] 
"Icon"="%ProgramFiles%\\Windows Defender\\EppManifest.dll,7" 
"Position"="Bottom"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\Shell\Toggle Windows Defender\command] 
@="\"C:\\YOUR\\NSUDO\\FOLDER\\NSudo.exe\" -U:P -ShowWindowMode:Hide cmd /c  \"sc query WinDefend | find /I \"STATE\" | find \"STOPPED\" && (\"C:\\YOUR\\NSUDO\\FOLDER\\NSudo.exe\" -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide sc start WinDefend & exit/b) || (\"C:\\YOUR\\NSUDO\\FOLDER\\NSudo.exe\" -U:T -ShowWindowMode:Hide sc stop WinDefend)\""
```

The WinDefend service can only be stopped with TrustedInstaller privileges. So we need [NSudo](https://github.com/M2Team/NSudo/releases/tag/6.2) to run this script as TrustedInstaller

Comment: This icon is in the right-click context menu?

Comment: Yes. this REG file creates a right-click context menu toggle switch

Comment: The few guides I just checked online suggest there is no need to refresh Explorer.exe or reset the computer for icons in the context menus to update. I don't know what mechanism Windows uses to update these. Have you tried just adding the icon changing method to the script that switches the service state? What happened when you did?

Comment: That's what I don't know how to do--adding the icon changing method to the script. I want it to be able to change icons when it switches the service state.

Comment: The basic issue here then is that you are trying to do TWO things in a context-menu command rather than one thing. So, instead of placing the action command in the context menu, place an argument to run a script, and then place the action commands in the script that runs, including the information necessary to adjust the icon. A script can more easily do multiple things in a single run.

Comment: The context menu command works but uses only a single icon. Is it not possible to insert a script in the command that changes the icons?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd